# Line profiling python code running as background service

Tags: python, profiling

I am aware of the way independent scripts are profiled using kerprof/profile/cProfile. But how can I profile python web application running as background service/long running application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some drill down and exploring potential solutions; I came up with following solution:

1. Add the following function into source file and decorate the original function to profile with @do_cprofile

   ```
   import cProfile

   def do_cprofile(func):
       def profiled_func(*args, **kwargs):
           profile = cProfile.Profile()
           try:
               profile.enable()
               result = func(*args, **kwargs)
               profile.disable()
               return result
           finally:
               profile.dump_stats('/tmp/profile_bin.prof')
       return profiled_func
   ```
2. Convert the generated `/tmp/profile_bin.prof` to human readable file

   ```
   import pstats

   f = open('/tmp/human_readable_profile.prof', 'w')
   stats = pstats.Stats('/tmp/profile_bin.prof', stream=f)
   stats.sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats()
   f.close()
   ```